# Convert time to hour range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to convert a time to hour range. I have two columns like this

```
date                       time
2008-01-02                 00:05
2008-01-02                 00:15
2008-01-02                 01:10
2008-01-02                 01:15
2008-01-02                 02:15
2008-01-02                 02:25
```

Now, How can I get result like this

```
  date                      hour_range
2008-01-02                 00-01
2008-01-02                 00-01
2008-01-02                 01-02
2008-01-02                 01-02
2008-01-02                 02-03
2008-01-02                 02-03
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what I have tried :  SELECT DATEPART(hour,time) FROM  record ORDER BY DATEPART(hour,time)

Comment: cool, not far then just need to add one hour to the time and take the hour part. I posted an answer

Comment: What is the hour_range you would want to see for time = 23:40?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to get that output:

`SELECT 
    colDate, 
    RIGHT ('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, colTime)), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, colTime) + 1), 2) AS timeRange
FROM
    tblTest`

But i would suggest, to create a range in the presentation layer like an application. I dont think this should be done in the database

Here a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1427c/8)

Comment: Excellent , Hats off - deterministicFail

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
 SELECT DATEPART(hour,time) thishour, DATEPART(hour,DATEADD(hh,1,time)) nexthour from record order by datepart(hour,time)
```